# How the URI on constructed from Location header?

Tags: http, redirect, user-agent, http-status-code-302

The GET request to a "http://fakedomain.com/my/abc/redirect.php?url=www.example.com" URL results into following response header,

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 30 Apr 2018 07:39:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Location: www.example.com
Content-Length: 40
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

How does server prepare/User agent prepare the URL from this location header.

Does it send redirect request to "**www.example.com**"?
OR
Does it send redirect request to  "**http://fakedomain.com/my/abc/www.example.com**" ?

And why it will build URL like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does it send redirect request to `www.example.com`? Or does it send redirect request to `http://fakedomain.com/my/abc/www.example.com`?

The request should be redirected to `http://fakedomain.com/my/abc/www.example.com`.

The [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) says the following regarding the [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header (highlight is mine):

> [**7.1.2.  Location**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2)
>
> The `Location` header field is used in some responses to refer to a
> specific resource in relation to the response.  The type of
> relationship is defined by the combination of request method and
> status code semantics.
>
> ```
>  Location = URI-reference
> ```
>
> **The field value consists of a single URI-reference.** [...]

The [URI-reference](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1) concept is define as follows in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) (highlight is mine):

> [**4.1.  URI Reference**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1)
>
> URI-reference is used to denote the most common usage of a resource
> identifier.
>
> ```
>  URI-reference = URI / relative-ref
> ```
>
> A URI-reference is either a URI or a relative reference.  **If the
> URI-reference's prefix does not match the syntax of a scheme followed
> by its colon separator, then the URI-reference is a relative
> reference.** [...]

So `www.example.com` should be interpreted as a [*relative reference*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) and not as an [*absolute URI*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.3).

The `www.example.com` situation is described as [*suffix reference*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.5) in the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986): it has the same syntax as a relative-path reference and cannot be used in contexts where a relative reference is expected (highlight is mine):

> [**4.5.  Suffix Reference**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.5)
>
> The URI syntax is designed for unambiguous reference to resources and
> extensibility via the URI scheme.  However, as URI identification and
> usage have become commonplace, traditional media (television, radio,
> newspapers, billboards, etc.) have increasingly used a suffix of the
> URI as a reference, consisting of only the authority and path
> portions of the URI, such as
>
> ```
>  www.w3.org/Addressing/
> ```
>
> or simply a DNS registered name on its own.  Such references are
> primarily intended for human interpretation rather than for machines,
> with the assumption that context-based heuristics are sufficient to
> complete the URI (e.g., most registered names beginning with `www`
> are likely to have a URI prefix of `http://`).  Although there is no
> standard set of heuristics for disambiguating a URI suffix, many
> client implementations allow them to be entered by the user and
> heuristically resolved.
>
> Although this practice of using suffix references is common, it
> should be avoided whenever possible and should never be used in
> situations where long-term references are expected.  The heuristics
> noted above will change over time, particularly when a new URI scheme
> becomes popular, and are often incorrect when used out of context. [...]
>
> **As a URI suffix has the same syntax as a relative-path reference, a
> suffix reference cannot be used in contexts where a relative
> reference is expected.**  As a result, suffix references are limited to
> places where there is no defined base URI, such as dialog boxes and
> off-line advertisements.